# How can I assign values to dataset based on time and overlapping numerical ranges? - SAS

Tags: sas, overlap, transpose

I have a credit card transaction dataset (let's call it "Trans") with transaction amount, *zip code*, and *date*. I have another dataset (let's call it "Key") that lists sales tax rates based on *date* and *geocode*. The Key dataset also includes a range of zip codes associated with each geocode represented by 2 variables: Zip Start and Zip End.

Because Geocodes don't align with zip codes, some of the zip code ranges overlap. If this happens, I want to use the lowest sales tax rate associated with the zip code shown in Trans.

Trans dataset:

```
TransAmount TransDate TransZip
$200 01/07/1998 90010
$12 02/09/2002 90022
```

Key dataset:

```
Geocode Rate StartDate EndDate ZipStart ZipEnd
1001 .0825 199701 200012 90001 90084
1001 .085 200101 200812 90001 90084
1002 .0825 199701 200012 90022 90024
1002 .08 200101 200812 90022 90024
```

Desired output:

```
TransAmount TransDate TransZip Rate
$200 01/07/1998 90010 .0825
$12 02/09/2002 90022 .08
```

I used this basic SQL code in SAS, but I run into the problem of overlapping zip codes.

```
 proc sql;
 create table output as
 select a.*, b.zipstart, b.zipend, b.startdate, b.enddate, b.rate
 from Trans.CA_Zip_Cd_Testing a left join Key.CA_rates b
  on a.TranZip ge b.zipstart
  and a.TranZip le b.zipend
  and a.TransDate ge b.StartDate
  and a.transDate le b.EndDate
;
quit;
```

Comment: a) Why is `excel` in the tag list?  b) How about trying to create a zipcode level table first which has the lowest rate that way first, then use that in your sql above?

Comment: Thanks Joe. 
a) the Key dataset is in Excel, so perhaps the solution could be done in Excel, as you allude to in b) That was my first thought, but with 2500+ unique zipcodes and overlaps it's still tricky. Plus i dont have a lot of experience working with matricies in SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way to do this as far as the query portion is to just add a subquery to get the min rate.

```
Select t.transamount, t.transdate,t.transzip
        ,(Select MIN(rate) from Key where t.transzip between ZipStart and ZipEnd and t.transdate between startdate and enddate) 'Rate'
from trans t
```

You could also do it as subquery and join on it.

Comment: Tested it on a sample and it seems to work just fine. Thanks! A+ for keeping it succinct.

Comment: The answer worked well, but it takes an inordinate amount of time to run compared with my other queries (40 min on a 10% sample of the data). Could you elaborate on the other option using a subquery and join logic? I'm not sure how to join it since it is essentially a conditional lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The SAS SQL Optimizer can be good sometimes. Other times, it can be a challenge. This code is going to be a bit more complicated, but it will likely be faster, and subject to size constraints on your key table.

```
data key;
set key;
   dummy_key=1;
run;

data want(drop=dummy_key geocode rate startDate endDate zipStart zipEnd rc i);
if _n_ = 1 then do;
 if 0 then set key;
 declare hash k (dataset:'key',multidata:'y');
 k.defineKey('dummy_key');
 k.defineData('geocode','rate','startdate','enddate','zipstart','zipend');
 k.defineDone();
end;
call missing (of _all_);
set trans;
dummy_key=1;

rc = k.find();
do i=1 to 1000 while (rc=0);
transZipNum = input(transZip,8.); *converts character zip to number. if its    already a number then remove;
zipStartNum = input(zipStart,8.);
zipEndNum = input(zipEnd,8.);

if startDate <= transDate <= endDate then do;
     if zipStartNum <= transZipNum <= zipEndNum then do;
          rate_out = min(rate_out,rate);
     end;
end;
rc=k.find_next();
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting an error that the "Variable dummy_key is not on file WORK.KEY". I tried setting dummy_key=1 after the 'set key;' statement, but this still doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: It would have to be added in a preparatory step. I edited the code to reflect what would have to happen.

Comment: Thanks. if the actual Key file is 12000 records, do I have to increase the do loop to cover?

Comment: Yes. The i=1 to 1000 code is a "best practice" to prevent an infinite loop. As such, it needs to be large enough to iterate through all possible rows. I would change it to a number higher than the highest possible rows that you think would be in the key table.